# React: 'map' function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching a list of objects.
Using map function should display a list but there wasn't. I checked if it was saved to 'useState' via console.log(posts), and yes there was a list of objects. My only problem is I cant display it to the browser. Also, I already attached the necessary scripts for 'react', 'reactDOM', and 'babel'.

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %} {% block body %}
<div id="index"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  const AllPosts = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/allposts")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data.posts);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
      <ul>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post, index) => {
            <li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>;
          })}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  const Index = () => {
    return <AllPosts />;
  };

  const container = document.getElementById("index");
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
  root.render(<Index />);
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I wanted to return each object on the list in an li tag, however, there was no data when I inspected it on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use {} in an arrow function as shown below, you must return.

```
  <ul>
    {posts &&
      posts.map((post, index) => {
         return (
            <li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>;
         );
      })}
  </ul>
```

However, if you do not use {}, it returns automatically.

```
  <ul>
    {posts &&
      posts.map((post, index) => <li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>;
      )}
  </ul>
```

The two codes above do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to add `return` to the map function.

```
posts.map((post, index) => {
  return <li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>;
})}
```

Comment: the ul tag is already inside the return statement.

Comment: my bad, you were right, i just need to return it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should return the tag like this:

```
          posts.map((post, index) => {
              return(<li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>);
          })}
```

or this:

```
{posts &&
          posts.map((post, index) => 
              <li key={index}>{`Try ${index}`}</li>
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statement inside the map function. As a result, the JSX for the list items is not being returned, and that's why you're not seeing any data in the browser.

{posts &&
posts.map((post, index) => {
return {`Try ${index}`};
})}